# Calling socket.emit('init', 'data') from client side javascript function does not execute.

Tags: javascript, socket.io

On client side:

```
<a href='javascript:callInit();'> Get Init </a>
```

Client side html includes following script above:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
 function callInit(){
  alert('inside callInit');
  socket.emit('init', 'data');
}
</script>
```

On Server-side:

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('socket connection established');
    socket.on('init', function(data){
    console.log('init invoked');
    init();
    });
 });
```

In the above code: `alert('inside callInit')` executes. `console.log('socket connection established');` executes. But `console.log('init invoked`);` does not execute.

Comment: Anything on the browser's console?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yes the alert function. thats all.

Comment: The console.... Not the browser window @Swagg

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yes, it says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' for "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" and 'Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined' for "localhost:3000/:1"

Comment: @Neal I am the same person who asked that question. This point is not answered there!

Comment: @Neal please read the edit there.

Comment: @Swagg you should **not** be asking the same question twice in 5 hours....

Comment: @Neal I am not, if u understand that, the question there was answered, using jQuery. Here I'm asking a more specific question how to perform the same action without jQuery.

Comment: No... You asked **nothing** about jQuery in the duplicate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `io.connection(...)` is **async** and the socket was probably not connected at the time the `callInit` function was called.

You might want to add a `on('connect', ....)` to the browser side socket connection and an `on('error', ...)` to check for connections and errors

Comment: Huh? Please read the documentation....

Comment: http://socket.io/#how-to-use is the documentation. how do u do sockets.on('connection') is not here atleast.

Comment: besides. i'm calling the function callInit manually, so i can manage the time gap, for the connection to happen. So there may be another explanation for it